# Masonry.js working with static html but not content added dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have a page using masonry.js to tile the divs in a pinterest type layout.

The css and script work fine if I use static html but if I use a function to load the content then the masonry layout isn't applied

This works (when I put the HTML directly into the .grid div)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    // set itemSelector so .grid-sizer is not used in layout
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    // use element for option
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true,
    gutter: 10
    })

    // layout Masonry after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.masonry('layout');
    });
    });
</script>
```

However when I add the function below which loads exactly the same HTML into .grid div the masonry style doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)
    var leagueid = <?php echo "1";?>;
    $('.grid').load("league_news1.php", {'group_no':track_load,'leagueid':leagueid}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way I should be running this?  I've tried putting the content loader first then masonry but that doesn't work.   Should masonry be checking that the content is loaded first? If so how? Should I be using something other then document.ready?

Thanks in advance for any help with this one!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have loaded content, you should then run the masonry function in the callback:

```
 $('.grid').load("league_news1.php",
                 {'group_no':track_load,'leagueid':leagueid}, 
                 function() {
                     track_load++;
                     var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
                          // set itemSelector so .grid-sizer is not used in layout
                          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                          // use element for option
                          columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                          percentPosition: true,
                          gutter: 10
                        })

                        // layout Masonry after each image loads
                        $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
                            $grid.masonry('layout');
                        });
                    });
                 }
 ); //load first group
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.   I understand what you're saying but it actually makes the layout worse.   With my code the divs are stacking with a space between them (which isn't what I want) but implementing your code makes it even worse with all the divs on top of each other - so only one is actually visible ( I think that's the imagesLoaded() function  not working corrrectly in your code)